# GetScreenSize function for C++; "no suitable user defined conversion" (Winforms)

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Trying to make a Winforms program in C++, so far everything else works, though I am unable to get the screen size automatically, does anyone know how to overstep this problem?

> ```
>   // Utility to get screen size of the user using the application
>   public:
>       static int GetScreenSize() 
>       {
>           int x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max;
>           x_min = y_min = int::MaxValue;
>           x_max = y_max = int::MaxValue;
>
>           for each(Screen screen in Screen::AllScreens)
>           {
>               // equiv of 'var' (C#) is 'auto' in C++
>               auto bounds = screen.Bounds;
>               x_min = Math::Min(x_min, bounds.X);
>               y_min = Math::Min(y_min, bounds.Y);
>               x_max = Math::Max(x_max, bounds.X);
>               y_max = Math::Max(y_max, bounds.Y);
>           }
>       }
> ```

[**Automatic Screen size function**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ9aT.png)

[**Error; "no suitable user-defined conversion from "System::Windows::Forms::Screen ^" to "System::Windows::Forms::Screen" exists"**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeJPc.png)

Comment: Not remembering nearly anything about what little managed C++ I looked at eons ago when MS tried in earnest to sell us on it.... isn't that supposed to be `for each(Screen^ screen in Screen::AllScreens)` ? Fairly equivalent [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=net-5.0). Methinks you're missing the handle-declarator.

Comment: The error message really tells you all you need: Your type (`System::Windows::Forms::Screen`) and the expected type (`System::Windows::Forms::Screen^`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested, we should use `Screen^ screen` to replace `Screen screen` to solve the error.

You could try the following code to get screen size of the user using the application.

```
public:
        static String^ GetScreenSize()
        {
            int x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max;
            x_min = y_min = int::MaxValue;
            x_max = y_max = int::MaxValue;

            for each (Screen^ screen in Screen::AllScreens)
            {
                // equiv of 'var' (C#) is 'auto' in C++
                auto bounds = screen->Bounds;
                x_min = Math::Min(x_min, bounds.X);
                y_min = Math::Min(y_min, bounds.Y);
                x_max = Math::Max(x_max, bounds.X);
                y_max = Math::Max(y_max, bounds.Y);
            }
            String^ result= String::Format("X min is {0}, Y min is {1},X max is {2},Y max is {3}", x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max);
            return result;
        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        String^ result=GetScreenSize();
        MessageBox::Show(result);
    }
```

Note: I changed the return type from int to string, which can get the result.

Result:

[image]